# product and coproduct of the subgroups of intergers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the category of the subgroups $n\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ of the group of integers with addition, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. The morphisms in $\mathcal{S}$ are the inclusion maps. What are the product and coproduct of any two objects $a\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathcal{S}$?

Is it true that the product is $d\mathbb{Z}$, with $d=lcm(a,b)$ and coproduct is $a\mathbb{Z}\cup b\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Surely the coproduct is $a\Bbb Z+b\Bbb Z$? In a poset, the product is the meet and the coproduct is the join (where these exist) and the present problem is just a case of this.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I reversed the order; I had in mind divisibility order which is the opposite of containment! The coproduct is gcd and the product is lcm.